# How to Return a struct as json with .NetCore

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm moving a .Net Framework WebAPI to .Net Core.  With Framework (notably using Newtonsoft.Json), a class or a struct is  returned as xml or json according to the Accept header.

With .Net Core, structs are always coming back as empty json: e.g. `[{},{}]`.

Starting from a pared down new project (i.e. WeatherController), how do I get this to properly serialize and return non-empty json?

```
public struct MyStructure
{
    public double A;
    public double B;
}
    
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyStructureController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<MyStructure> Get()
    {
        return new List<MyStructure>
        {
            new MyStructure(){A = 1.2d, B = 5.6d},
            new MyStructure(){A = 2.2d, B = 3.3d},
        };
    }
}
//desired response:  [{"X":1.2,"Y":5.6},{"X":2.2,"Y":3.3}]
```

I'm not finding what I need in the [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-supported-collection-types?pivots=dotnet-5-0), nor the [unsupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#types-without-built-in-support), serialization documentation but I'm clearly overlooking something!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set `IncludeFields = true` in your `JsonSerializerOptions` - same for `class` `fields`). Or see the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69544369/304683) (re: `propeties`)

Comment: Yes! This works without modifying the struct, so accepted. `services.AddControllers()                .AddJsonOptions(options =>{options.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true;});`

Answer (score 4):

Try to do public properties instead of public variables. I think system.text.json only serializes public properties by default

Comment: just fyi - fields can be serialized (`IncludeFields = true`)

Comment: Yes, this works: `public double A { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having instance variables try to change them to properties with getter and setter methods.

```
public struct MyStructure
{
    public double A {get;set;}
    public double B {get;set;}
}
```

This will help you get the desired response

```
 [{"X":1.2,"Y":5.6},{"X":2.2,"Y":3.3}]
```